# How to Rotate Canvas Element on the X axis with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 2d

I would like to know if there is a specific method to make this kind of animation?

Rotation Axis X:
https://gyazo.com/78c66d5cd8fc0bcb5ab2e0c3ddb77508

Is it possible to do with canvas 2d or to reproduce something similar ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to do with canvas 2d or to reproduce something similar ?

Yes, it is possible to achieve this effect on a 2d canvas - but it takes an awful lot of coding to do it in vanilla JS.

One approach is to create a second, hidden canvas in which you generate the scene that you want to animate in the existing, visible canvas. Then you need to copy the hidden canvas to the visible canvas on a 1px hight row-by-row basis, calculating the appropriate destination x, y and width values to emulate the 3d effect. However, the result will often include a Moire effect (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) - the simplest way to get rid of it is to very gently blur the visible canvas until the unwanted interference patterns disappear.

Clearly the above is not an ideal solution - if you can use a WebGL canvas you can make use of 3d canvas libraries (for instance, three.js) which should make generating the effect a lot easier. A CSS approach - as outlined in another answer here - would be an even better solution!

If you really can't move away from the 2d canvas, then you can achieve the effect using the Scrawl-canvas JS library (disclaimer: I maintain this library) - see an example here: https://scrawl-v8.rikweb.org.uk/demo/dom-015.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try the different proposition, thanks for the different approach it's really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Rather than Canvas, CSS animations would be an ideal candidate for this sort of thing.

eg.

```css
body {
  background-color: #444;
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

.outer {
  perspective: 500px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
  width: 200px;
}

.inner {
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  transform-origin: top left;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: slideDown;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 50pt;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<br/>
<center>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">Texte</div>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, i know about the css solution but the environnement im using use canvas only, I don't know if there is something similar as this css property but for canvas?